# Messagebox.Show raises combo box SelectedIndex/Value Changed Events?

Tags: c#, data-binding, event-handling

Consider a form with a dataGridView bound to a strongly typed dataset.  A combo box exists on the top to allow the user to select an employee.  Once selected, the gataGridView's dataset is filled based on the employee's ID.

Some data entry is done on the dataGridView and once completed the user saves.  In order to keep the user from accidently moving to another employee and deleting what they keyed, I prompt them to save is the dataset HasChanges() is true.

I was catching this piece of code in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combo box but this also raises the event in the SelectedValueChanged

```
private void checkSaveChanges()
{
    this.Validate();
    this.laborTicketBindingSource.EndEdit();

    if (dP_LaborTicket.HasChanges())
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your changes?", "Save before closing?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dP_LaborTicket);
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the event that gets raised:

```
private void cmbEmployeeID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkSaveChanges();

    if (cmbTransactionDate != null && cmbEmployeeID.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        string selectedDate = cmbTransactionDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string selectedEmployee = cmbEmployeeID.SelectedValue.ToString();

        this.laborTicketTableAdapter.Fill(this.dP_LaborTicket.LaborTicket, selectedEmployee, selectedDate);
    }

}
```

So stepping into this once I change a record and move to another employee, it steps into checkSaveChanges.  Successfully validates and ends the edit and checks if it has changes (which it does).

After executing MessageBox.Show, the program is suddenly sent back to the cmbEmployeeID_SelectedIndexChanged event, where it calls checkSaveChanges yet again.  This only happens twice though, and even if they say yes or no, the code within the prompting block runs.

How in the world is MessageBox.Show calling this twice?  If I comment that line out this does not happen...

*EDIT*
As a bonus piece of information, the combo box AutoCompleteMode was set to SuggestAppend (Shows a dropdown as your typing) and DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList.

I changed the AutoCompleteMode to Append and this doesn't happen anymore, it seems to only happen with the SuggestAppend Mode...

Comment: I would guess that one of the controls' LostFocus events is causing the SelectedIndexChanged to fire again. Showing the messagebox causes your main window to lose focus, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sven could be right that the `MessageBox.Show` will cause the dropdown to loose focus.

One way to work around this problem could be to detect if the event is already executing using a private boolean in the class. You'd then get something like this:

```
private bool fIsInEvent = false;

private void cmbEmployeeID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!fIsInEvent)
  {
    fIsInEvent = true;
    try
    {
      // your code
    }
    finally { fIsInEvent = false; }
  }
}
```